# Why does the prismic starter app for django not work?

Tags: django

The [prismic.io](https://prismic.io/) starter [app](https://github.com/prismicio/python-django-lesbonneschoses) for Django fails on

```
StructuredText' object has no attribute 'Text'
```

from the line `<span>{% filter default:"Product" %}{% get_text product "product.name" %}{% endfilter %}</span>` in the `index.html` template. It is clearly occuring in the `get_text` filter tag

The tag is simply

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_text(document, field, default=""):
    value = document.get_text(field)
    return value if value is not None else default
```

So why is this failing, why doesn't `get_text` just grab the value?

Comment: How is your model defined?. Also `return value or default` should do the trick in your return statement

Comment: @karthikr you can see (and even clone) the full source from the app link in my post.

Comment: nope.. your models.py are empty. Also, it is expected that you paste relevant parts of the code as a part of the question, rather than pasting links.

Comment: Yes the models.py are empty. This is not my code, it's a publicly available django starter kit for prismic, an interface to their API. I did paste some pertinent code from the template in question and from the tag in question in addition to the repo link, if you feel for some reason that the question should have some additional source from the github repo then feel free to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `get_text` does not work on `StructuredText` fragments, we need to use the `get_title` tag which under the scenes uses `.get_structured_text(field).get_title().text`. Thus making the replacements `get_text` --> `get_title` in the templates in the Django starter kit makes things work.

I guess this should be changed in the repo.